# Is the Bollogg still a cyclops in editions after 2001?

Tags: 13-lives-captain-bluebear, zamonia

In my 2001 edition, translated into English by John Brownjohn in 2000 from the 1999 text by Moers, when Bluebear is becoming acquainted with the dream organ...

> The images were projected on the back of the Bollogg's eyes.

("Eyes" plural). But then...

> There were images from the childhood and adolescence of the Cyclops, when he was still small and rode mammoths.

I'm just curious if this was amended in later editions?

Comment: Is there any reason why you use the word "amended"? If you have a reason to believe that the use of the term cyclops is a mistake, it would be interesting to add it to the question.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I am puzzled by the apparent contradiction between eyes plural and cyclops. I've edited the question. Thanks

Comment: Ah, now I understand the point. Yes, in the 2005 edition too the Bollog is repeatedly referred to as having eyes (plural), while it also described as being a cyclops. As you say a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [2005 edition](https://archive.org/details/1312livesofcapta00moer/) from Overlook Press, the Bollogg is described in exactly the same terms, with several references to it having "eyes" in the plural, for example

> Situated behind the Bollogg's eyes... was the dream organ.

However the Bollogg is defined in the text as:

> The Bollogg [Cyclops stupidus] belongs to the Giant Cyclops family,
> which includes all **one-eyed, outsize life forms** over 75 feet in
> height. Although Giant Cyclopses do not exceed 500 feet as a rule, a
> Bollogg can grow to a height of two miles and is thus the only living
> creature to he classified among Zamonia's exceptional natural
> disasters.

It seems very definite that the Bollogg *is* a cyclops, and so the references to its "eyes" must be a slip/contradiction. As of 2005 it appears that the mistake has still not been corrected. From the [isfdb page](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?998069) it seems that a slightly later version from 2008 is available from the Paw Prints publisher, but I do not have access to it to check if that also contains the error.

Comment: I had a look into the german original of 1999 and there both times (in context of the dream organ) only one eye is mentioned :)

Comment: @Allerleirauh, thank you for that - it seems to suggest the translation into English brought about the pluralised eyes.